# How to create a QR code that links to URL?

Tags: qr-code

I am just a beginner who is trying to play around with QR codes. 
I would like to try to learn how to embed URL Links in QR codes.

How do we do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type your URL into the text box on [this page](http://createqrcode.appspot.com/) and click "Create QR Code".

The scanner that the end-user translates the QR code with is (usually) smart enough to detect it as a URL and open it as such.

If you would like to create QR codes directly on your Android phone, install [QR Droid](https://market.android.com/details?id=la.droid.qr&hl=en) from the Market. It has a "Share" tab that allows you to embed almost anything (including URLs) into a QR code.

Comment: For more information if you want to generate the QR code yourself see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply but what I really need to know is to create a QR code myself in the phone....

Comment: Updated my answer with phone instructions.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using phpqr code script the use below statements in your code

```
$website = "http://www.example.com/";
QRcode::png($website);
```